# Spotipy TypeError when trying to get songs from official Spotify account (Python)[SOLVED- Was using a depreciated function]

Tags: python, typeerror, spotify, spotipy

I have a set of functions that works as expected when I use my own Spotify username or a friend's, but when I use 'Spotify' it either runs indefinitely or gives me TypeError

How I am accessing the Spotify API:

```
load_dotenv()
cid = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID")
secret = os.getenv("SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET")
redirect = os.getenv("REDIRECT_URI")
username = os.getenv("SPOTIFY_USERNAME")
scope = 'user-library-read'


token = spotipy.prompt_for_user_token(username=username, scope=scope, client_id=cid, client_secret=secret, redirect_uri=redirect)
oauth = spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret, redirect_uri=redirect, username=username)
session = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

Relevant Code:

```
def get_audio_features(uris):
    data = []
    batch_size = 50
    for i in range(0, len(uris), batch_size):
        batch_uris = uris[i:i+batch_size]
        features = session.audio_features(batch_uris)
        for feature in features:
            if feature is not None:
                data.append([
                    feature['danceability'],
                    feature['energy'],
                    feature['key'],
                    feature['loudness'],
                    feature['mode'],
                    feature['speechiness'],
                    feature['acousticness'],
                    feature['instrumentalness'],
                    feature['liveness'],
                    feature['valence'],
                    feature['tempo'],
                    feature['id']
                ])
    return data


def get_user_playlists(user):
    user_playlist_ids = []
    playlists = session.user_playlists(user)
    while playlists:
        for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
            user_playlist_ids.append(playlist['uri'][-22:])
        if playlists['next'] is not None:
            playlists = session.next(playlists)
        else:
            playlists = None
    return user_playlist_ids



def get_playlist_tracks(playlist_uris):
    playlist_track_ids = []
    for uri in playlist_uris:
        tracks = session.playlist_tracks(uri, limit=50)['items']
        for track in tracks:
            print(track)
            if track is not None:
                playlist_track_ids.append(track['track']['id'])
    return playlist_track_ids


def get_user_playlists_tracks_audio_features(user):
    user_playlists = get_user_playlists(user)
    user_plalist_tracks = get_playlist_tracks(user_playlists)
    user_playlist_tracks_audio_features = get_audio_features(user_plalist_tracks)
    return user_playlist_tracks_audio_features

user_playlist_tracks_audio_features = get_user_playlists_tracks_audio_features('Spotify')

print(user_playlist_tracks_audio_features)
```

When I run this with my `username` it outputs something like this:
`[[#, #, ..., id], [#, #, ..., id], ...]`

When I use 'Spotify' as the username I get this error:
`playlist_track_ids.append(track['track']['id'])  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

I tried fixing it by adding this if statement in `get_playlist_tracks()`: `if track is not None:`, but it still doesn't work *only* when I use Spotify as the username I want to get the songs from.

Then I added a `try: except: TypeError` and that seemed to run longer, but that seems like a poor fix for this, and it eventually just stops? It was printing each track with `print(track)`, but that stops after probably a few thousand lines and never reaches my final `print(user_playlist_tracks_audio_features)`.

I can provide any more details if necessary, thank you in advance for any advice or solutions.

Edit:
Since making this post, the code doesn't seem to run with any username now, and I am really lost as to what changed.

Edit2:
I think what I said in my last edit was due to running out of API calls for a short time, but my original issue of using 'Spotify' as the username still happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to answer my own question, I was using `session.playlist_tracks()` when I really should have been using `session.playlist()`. I was able to get out all the information I needed.

`playlist_tracks()` was what I was working with originally because I was just trying to get a foothold on how the library worked, it was depreciated in the version I was using but I ignored it because I couldn't find any information on why or if there was a replacement for it.

Using `playlist()` you are able to get information from any user's (probably) playlist, including 'Spotify'. And like I said in my edits, I believe my second issue was due to running out of API calls, but I'm not sure why it would run indefinitely without printing an error.